# How to loop through folders and rename extensions in a batch file?

Tags: windows, rename, batch-file, batch-rename

Selecting a single folder I could run

```
ren *.jpeg *.png
```

I have multiple folders. I want to create a batch file that will loop through all the folders and will rename the files within it.

For example I have folders `TEST1` and `TEST2` inside root directory `TEST`. I want to create a batch that will rename all the `.jpeg` files within `TEST1` and `TEST2` to `.png`.

```
FOR /R "E:\TEST\" %%G in (*.jpeg) DO ren *.jpeg *.png
```

I am getting an error:

> The system can not find the file specified

I don't understand the issue.

Comment: I think the error occurs for each folder that does not have "jpeg" files inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not applying the `for` command to the `ren` action.

```
for /r "E:\test\" %%G in (*.jpeg) do ren "%%~G" *.png
```

You need to change `%%` to `%` if you are doing this interactively, and not in a batch file.

The `~` strips quotes, which are re-added, to avoid any possible errors with paths which contain spaces.

Comment: ok, your solution is smaller :) - I used an old one I have in my bat library. I did not tested yours but I believe on you.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you want a slightly shorter one-liner, here's how do to it with a combination of the [`REN` commmand](http://jpsoft.com./help/ren.htm) and the [`GLOBAL` commmand](http://jpsoft.com./help/global.htm) in [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccle_cmd_replacement.html):

```
GLOBAL REN *.JPEG *.PNG
```

Use `GLOBAL`'s `/I` option if you want to ignore any non-zero exit codes from the `REN` command, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution is below.

Set the variables in section "variables":

```
@echo off

::only to tell user what this bat are doing
echo.1.initializing...

::enable that thing to allow, for example, incremental counter in a for loop :)
echo.- EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::variables
echo.- variables
:: - place here the absolute root path of your files
set path2work="C:\Documents and Settings\ubirajara2\Desktop\Nova pasta"
set extension2exclude=jpeg
set extension2put=png

::only an auxiliar variable
set pathbak=%cd%

::go to %path2work% and its drive letter
echo.- entering the path you want
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('echo.%path2work%') do %%~di
cd %path2work%

::search all subfolders and save them to a temp file
echo.- searching for subfolders
echo.%path2work%>%temp%\tmpvar.txt
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('dir /s /b /on /ad') do echo."%%i">>%temp%\tmpvar.txt

::execute command for root folder and all found subfolders
echo.
echo.2.executing...
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in (%temp%\tmpvar.txt) do (
  cd %%i
  echo.- in folder: %%i
  for /f "delims=¯" %%j in ('dir /b /on /a-d *.%extension2exclude%') do (
    set newname=%%~nj.%extension2put%
    echo.- renaming from "%%j" to "!newname!"...
    ren "%%j" "!newname!"
  )
)

echo.
echo.3.exiting...
::return to %pathbak% and its driveletter
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('echo.%pathbak%') do %%~di
cd %pathbak%

@echo on
```

Comment: a "file not found" appears for each folder that does not have "jpeg" files on it.

Comment: Whoa.  Crazy stuff.  And what is that business with `%PATH%`?

Comment: well, when I created my first version of a renamer batch, I did not know about pushd and popd, haha. so "::go to %path% and its driveletter
" = pushd, ::return to %pathbak% and its driveletter = popd :)

Comment: but I think is is so didactic and a "more controlled" solution

Comment: I see.  You could just use `%SystemDrive%` if you wanted the system drive for whatever reason.

Comment: I do not want to use system drive, but the drive of paths I'm working with (they would be different of system drive) => general solution

Comment: so I can save the bat anywhere and work with a path anywhere

Comment: I think we are both on different planets, as that makes absolutely no sense to me.  `%PATH%` is a system environmental variable, which is used for where the OS should search for executables if it cannot find them in the current directory.  Try typing `echo.%path%` into CMD and see what it comes up with.  You use `%CD%` for what it looks like you are trying to do.

Comment: ach so :) i'm working with a local variable called path, not with the global one. well, i set that name for that bat, but it would be better to change to pathbak or something else (at really it is better to change to pushd, popd)

Comment: i know about path system environment variable, but in that case it does not help me. so, i'll change the variable name in bat :) and also later I'll delete some comments

Comment: changed variable name from "path" to "path2work" to avoid ambiguity with path system environment variable