# AutoHotkey - - loop through files and replace whitespace with _

Tags: autohotkey

With AutoHotkey, trying to loop through all jpg's in an absolute path and replace all white space with _ . I've been fighting with this for ages, only got this far:

```
#!l::


  Loop, C:\Users\me\Desktop\OM\renaming folder\*V1.jp*

    StringReplace, NewStr, OldStr, %A_SPACE%, +, All

   ;; StringReplace, A_LoopFileName, %A_LoopFileName%, %A_SPACE%, +, All ; also tried this, then I get an error about an illegal char in var name

    Return
```

Comment: Would you not consider using `ren` in a batch file? If so, this may help http://superuser.com/questions/309818/how-to-loop-through-folders-and-rename-extensions-in-a-batch-file as will this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919027/rename-files-using-batch

Comment: I considered, but I don't know batch and it's syntax looks like complete gibberish to me :)

Comment: I might have to go the batch way, then run it with AHK as part of the bigger programme I'm building with AHK.

Comment: Does this help http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/49201-rename-selected-filesfolder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filePath := "C:\Path\To\Images"

Loop, %filePath%\*V1.jp*
{
    newName := RegExReplace(A_LoopFileName, "\s", "_")
    FileMove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %filePath%\%newName%

    MsgBox % "New filename: " newName
}
```

This should do the trick. Just make sure you run this on a test-batch first so you don't accidentally rename all your images to something you didn't want.

If you don't intend to rename the images, just remove `FileMove, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, %filePath%\%newName%`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, and this will now serve as a base for me to further develop the script to remove other chars, etc. (as I am familiar with Regex)

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey is the wrong tool for the job, as you are on windows there are great programs such as Advanced Renamer http://www.advancedrenamer.com/

If you were on linux it's even easier, using Perl Rename (rename).

Both use standard regex.

Comment: Sure, I googled them all, but I wanted this functionality as part of a bigger single script.